# in_array analogue for Laravel Collection

Tags: php, laravel

I have a collection of model instances, and a model of the same type I want to determine the existence of in that collection.

Would it be possible to do so without using `toArray()`?

What I have now:

```
in_array($context->toArray(), $instance->contexts()->toArray());
```

What I want in pseudocode:

```
in_collection($context, $instance->contexts());
```

Comment: Basically [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-contains) ?

Comment: @ka_lin Yeah, that would be it. Must've missed it.

Comment: @ka_lin If you'd like, post it as an answer - you were first to do so so I'll accept yours over the other one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method for this since you are using `Collections` and it is called `contains()`, from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-contains) we have the following example:

```
$collection = collect(['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100]);

$collection->contains('Desk');

// true

$collection->contains('New York');
```

There is also a `containsStrict` which is similar and has the same signature but takes into account the variable type if not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

$collection = collect(['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100]);

$collection->contains('Desk');

// true

$collection->contains('New York');

// false